# PhantomJS return empty body

Tags: javascript, http-headers, phantomjs, headless-browser

I send request with headers(X-CSRF-Token, cookie etc) and get empty response, but when I do same with postman(chrome extension) I get correctly response.

Example of response (something like this):

```
<a href="img1.jpg" data-gallery><img src="img11.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a href="img2.jpg" data-gallery><img src="img21.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

UPD:

my code

```
page.open(url, settings, function(status, a, b) {  
  var response = page.evaluate(function() {
    return document.body.outerHTML
  });
  console.log('>>', JSON.stringify(response))
});
```

run:

> phantomjs --ssl-protocol=TLSv1 --debug=no --load-images=no --ignore-ssl-errors=yes --web-security=true  test.js

Comment: GIve us more information about empty response. Maybe, when empty response is returned, it's ´bad request´, ´internal error´

Comment: exactly "<body></body>"

Comment: Try to execute in debug mode and no ignore ssl errors. It seems  to be SSL error, try to specify SSL path (`--ssl-certificates-path`)

Comment: Also modify: `page.evaluate(function() {return document.body.outerHTML  });` to `page.content`

Comment: page.content return <html><head></head><body></body></html>; debug mode not print any errors

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: These events are not calling; phantom is 1.9.8

Comment: I don't know what the issue is and I don't want to make wild guesses. Try to upgrade to PhantomJS 2

Comment: Which URL are you testing?

Comment: http://realt-info.com/variants/get-photo

Answer (score 1):

This 2 params should be added: `--ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any`
to phantomjs run command